# Display article from backend and style it with html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, backend

I have backend that is returning me whole article body text as String. On my website I want to create each article in different HTML/CSS style, for example have `<br>` tag to break article when it is too long. But some articles will not be long, so I can't place `<br>` tag inside my frontend component.

As my frontend component is not changing based on size of this text, I came up with an idea to store `<br>` tags directly inside article String texts. But data is coming as a string with `<br>` tags in it, the tags are treated also as a string, so it has no effect on styling.

Should I somehow escape these tags from string? Or is there a better way to do it? I don't have idea how it should be done properly.

Comment: what platform is your backend using?  How do your "receive" each article?

Comment: @willman I'm using AWS DynamoDB for backend and ReactJS for frontend.

Comment: @willman I receive article by doing simple HTTP GET, in return I got object with, article-title, article-id, article-body-text. And this body text should be in different styles, longer texts should have breaklines in it, or some words should be bolder but im not sure how style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving raw html content that already has markup tags within it that you want to render in ReactJS, then you need to use React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute.  Depending on where you are holding the markup you received from the backend, your code somewhere within your `Render` function would look something like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state.recievedArticleRawText} />
```

see official documentation here for caveats and warnings on usage:  https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Essentially, the React team purposefully chose to name this `dangerously` because you should only use it if you 100% fully trust the value you are setting.  Do not ever set values input by the user to this attribute because it leaves holes for all kinds of injection.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. As I found out it is vulnerable for cross site scripting, anyone reading it should also know that. But for me it is fine. Thank you @willman .

Comment: yes, you are correct, that is in essence, why the React team name this attribute withe the `dangerously` prefix.  I have updated my answer to include appropriate warnings for any future readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `innerHTML`, then it should work correctly - given that you don't use `< br >`, as that's not a valid HTML entity (`<br />` and `<br>` are).

```js
const text1 = '1. This is a line< br >This should be the next line.'
const text2 = '2. This is a line<br>This should be the next line.'
const text3 = '3. This is a line<br />This should be the next line.'

document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = text1 // expected to not work correctly
document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = text2 // expected to work correctly
document.getElementById('text3').innerHTML = text3 // expected to work correctly
```

```html
<span id="text1"></span>
<hr />
<span id="text2"></span>
<hr />
<span id="text3"></span>
```

Comment: @muka.gergley I'm using ReactJS so calling document will not be a good option for this. You are right, < br > is not valid but when I write it without spaces, this editor will actually perform breakline and don't show the tag.